# Get immediate subdirectories in a directory on the server

Tags: php

I wrote a CMS in PHP. It works fine on most servers but I encountered a strange problem on my latest hosting account. This is either a path problem or a coding problem. The latter seems to be OK as this script works fine on all my other accounts, which is why I'm asking for help.

When I first install my CMS tool I run a script called "inventory.php" in which I attempt to get and display all the directories on the server from the location of my script, which is 2 or 3 directories down from the root, depending on the server. I try to use a global path that goes up to the root and from it to return all the directories it can find. If this file works then the entire CMS works; if not... well that's why I'm here.

Here's the code that scans the directories:

```
$main_root = realpath('../../');
echo '<b style="color:orange;">All The dirs on this server:</b><hr><br>';
$whats_on_the_server = array_filter(glob($main_root.'/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach($whats_on_the_server as $on_server) {
    $on_server = trim($on_server);
    if(stristr($on_server,'.')){    
        $arr1 = preg_split('^/^',$on_server);   
        echo $arr1[4].'<br>';
    }
}
```

The root is: chroot/home/account/ under which all my folders are located. I can't run a script from that directory, so I must access it from elsewhere. This works fine on other servers but on the one I currently use, it doesn't return anything if the path is set as above. It gets the directory contents if I set the path to a subfolder on the specific server, such as:

```
$main_root = realpath('../../SomeDir');
```

I must however get the name of all the directories located on the root.

Comment: Which operating system and web server?

Comment: @RmH: when you write "root", do you mean the filesystem root, document root or something else? Note that `<b>` and [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) aren't semantic; using them is a bad habit. A list element (ordered (`<ol>`) or unordered (`<ul>`)) would be more appropriate. Inline style should similarly only be used in certain cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So probably you don't have the privileges to access the root but do have privilegs to access the given subdirectories?

By the way, you can go to root by simply doing

```
$main_root = realpath('/');
```

which is always your most upper path!

Comment: Hi every one, thanks for the fast reply's ! 

"So probably you don't have the privileges to access the root but do have privilegs to access the given subdirectories?"

That is exactly right! That was my problem, i had to change servers as they would not grant me the necessary permissions.  

grate insight!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$main_root = dirname(__FILE__).'../../';
```

where `__FILE__` is a PHP constant for the current file.